# angularjs unit testing (cannot find propery of 'resolve' undefined angularjs testing)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do unit test of my angular app with karma. I am getting some error. Am i missing something? A
This my controller

```
(function () {
"use strict"
angular
    .module("myApp")

.controller("userCtrl",['$scope', '$state', 'userService', 'appSettings','md5','currentUser','$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $state, userService, appSettings,md5,currentUser, $rootScope) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        if($scope.password != null){
        var user ={
            username:$scope.username,
            password:md5.createHash($scope.password)
        }

            var getData = userService.login(user);
            getData.then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.loading = false;

                currentUser.setProfile(user.username, response.data.sessionId);

                $state.go('videos');
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        }else{
            $scope.msg = "Password field is empty!"
        }
    }
 }])
}());
```

### This is my test codes

```
'use strict';

describe('userCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  var scope, userCtrl, apiService,q, deferred, currentUser;

describe('$scope.login', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
        apiService = {
              login: function () {
                  deferred = q.defer();
                  return deferred.promise;
              };
            };
        });

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q, _currentUser_){
    var user ={name:'ali',password:'password'};
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    q = $q;

    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    userCtrl = $controller('userCtrl', {
        $scope:scope, 
        userService:apiService
      });
    //userService = _userService_;
    currentUser = _currentUser_;
  }));

    it('should call user service login', function() {
      spyOn(apiService, 'login').and.callThrough();
      scope.login();
      deferred.resolve(user);

      expect(apiService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('checks the password field', function() {
      scope.login();
      expect(scope.msg).toEqual('Password field is empty!');
    });

});
});
```

And i am getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9al.jpg)

Comment: You are not injecting the mock version of UserService into your controller. I can't really tell why from your code. You should try using the chrome debugger and stepping through the code as it runs the test.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: it seems that you login method not get called so thats why it got `undefined`. use `spyOn` instead of doing this.

Comment: you have missed to add `// We have to call apply for this to work
    $scope.$apply();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to test controller then use to spyon for service method and in case of service then use HttpBackend

```
    describe('Testing a Controller that uses a Promise', function() {
      var $scope;
      var $q;
      var deferred;

      beforeEach(module('search'));

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_, searchService) {
        $q = _$q_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

        // We use the $q service to create a mock instance of defer
        deferred = _$q_.defer();

        // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
        spyOn(searchService, 'search').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        // Init the controller, passing our spy service instance
        $controller('SearchController', {
          $scope: $scope,
          searchService: searchService
        });
      }));

      it('should resolve promise', function() {
        // Setup the data we wish to return for the .then function in the controller
        deferred.resolve([{
          id: 1
        }, {
          id: 2
        }]);

        // We have to call apply for this to work
        $scope.$apply();

        // Since we called apply, not we can perform our assertions
        expect($scope.results).not.toBe(undefined);
        expect($scope.error).toBe(undefined);
      });
    });
```

This for same using spyon for service method then use $appy method to make it work.